# How to put a texture inside of another texture

Tags: texturing, materials, bump

I wan't to have a bump texture, but its only visible in the black parts of this texture[image]

I think I maybe figured it out but for some reason the texture is flipped on either side[image]

[image]

Here's the node setup, there's no actual bump node in but thats cause I couldn't figure out how to do it with the bump, if someone knows pls lmk.
[image]

Comment: please add a screen shot showing your shader material

Comment: The easiest way is to use a Principle BSDF node and connect everything throught that

Comment: but like how do you make it so that the texture is only visible in the black parts of that first image

Answer (score 3):

You can use a Color mix node set to "screen" mode, to mix the bump texture with the Musgrave texture, so that you get a dark value only where both textures are dark.

Remember that color ramp nodes generally have black on left and white on right side (if inverted the results are inverted).

All four last shader nodes can be substituted with a Principled BSDF (with different results).

[image]

This is another approach, in which two different shaders (one with bump ond one without) are mixed.

Pro: the two shaders can have very different values.
Cons: slower render, as two shaders have to be evaluated instead of only one.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but is there a way to do it so that the black color isn't visible? I'm just trying to have it so that the bump texture is in the shape of the musgrave(ie the musgrave is the map for the bump) but you cant actually see the musgrave

Comment: In the first example just disconnect the color ramp output from the color input of the diffuse shader. In the second example disconnect the color ramp from the base color input of the 2nd Principled BSDF and set all values the same (except the bump inputs, one with and the other without).